# Tagging for Windows Active Directory questions

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions that have to do with authentication to a Windows AD (an Active Directory server or infrastructure), what's the best tag to use?

A lot of people were using [domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/domain), which seems pretty hopeless to me as a description.

I changed a few of those to [windows-active-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-active-directory) (because "windows-ad" just does not look right).  Then I finally noticed there was an existing [active-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) tag.   It probably makes sense to Windows people (though having the "windows" prefix is better for me), and it is shorter, possibly prettier.

I can imagine a [windows-domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain), though this may also be confusing.

I believe that the questions talking about "domain" which were not about web domains were all talking about attempting to "become part of the [windows] domain", so I believe these could all be "active directory" tagged as well.

Are there tags I'm missing which should be considered for deletion or tag synonyms?  Anyone have thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

I think we should drop the microsoft- because the standard term for it is active directory and everyone knows what that is and that's what people call it.

Older [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) questions are different. Most Windows admins I know refer to these as "NT Domains".

Becoming "part of a Windows domain" will be ambiguous, since you don't know if they mean an old NT style network (which is common in UNIX-land since that's what Samba 3.x uses) or if they mean "join an active directory".

So maybe:

- [active-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) for AD since that's what serverfault uses and it's common usage
- [domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/domain) or [windows-domain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain) both appear common on serverfault, in this case windows-domain makes sense so we don't mix it up with DNS domains, though I don't see how someone could mix one up with the other you never know.

Comment: Yeah, I like `active-directory` and `windows-domain` .  `domain` by itself is a bit confusing to me... perhaps others have a definite preference there.

Comment: @jgbelacqua Oh, and also have a mod do it so it doesn't bump up so many questions, I thought we were Ask Active Directory yesterday night, heh.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I got a little carried away.

Comment: @jgbelacqua Yeah I've only done that a hundred times myself.

Comment: @jorge @jgbelacqua I've merged `windows-active-directory` into `active-directory`